# Where is the magic number stated?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, peer-discovery

This has been bugging me. I’d have expected the magic number to be in the `chainParams.cpp` but I can’t find it.

Where is bitcoin's magic number stored in the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have been able to find them because they're encoded as separate bytes. You can find them in `src/chainparams.cpp`, currently on [lines 102–105](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/6d859cbd794a36ed1c0c72324a4ec54d029b3d3b/src/chainparams.cpp#L102). I found the code section after noticing that the Bitcoin Developer Guide [referred](https://btcinformation.org/en/developer-reference#constants-and-defaults) to the value as "Start String" and searching the code base for that term.

This is the relevant section of code.

```
    /**
     * The message start string is designed to be unlikely to occur in normal data.
     * The characters are rarely used upper ASCII, not valid as UTF-8, and produce
     * a large 32-bit integer with any alignment.
     */
    pchMessageStart[0] = 0xf9;
    pchMessageStart[1] = 0xbe;
    pchMessageStart[2] = 0xb4;
    pchMessageStart[3] = 0xd9;
```

Comment: OMG, I went code blind and was fixated on a single assignment. 

It’s right bloody there!!!